# Discord.js: components[0].components[0].options[1]: The specified option value is already used

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I was making a self-role menu using select menus feature and an error occurred while I was trying to run the command, the part of the command code:

```js
const Row5 = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
      new MessageSelectMenu()
      .setCustomId('pings')
      .setPlaceholder('Click to select the self-roles')
      .addOptions([
        {
          label: `Giveaways`,
          value: `giveaway`,
          emoji: ''
        },
        {
          label: `Tweets`,
          value: `twitterrrr`,
          emoji: '938517355879870474'
        },
        {
          label: `YouTube Uploads`,
          value: `uploads`,
          emoji: '879396250213027880'
        },
        {
          label: `Events`,
          value: `events`,
          emoji: ''
        },
        {
          label: `Chat Revive`,
          value: `revive`,
          emoji: ''
        },
        {
          label: `Hold`,
          description: `Used to select the same option again`,
          value: `hold`,
          emoji: '️'
        }
      ])
    )
```

Here is the full error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
components[0].components[0].options[1]: The specified option value is already used
components[0].components[0].options[2]: The specified option value is already used

[object Promise]
```

The error says that some option's values are not unique, but it is clearly not true, according to the code.

The interesting thing is - after I remove this part of code:

```js
{
          label: `Tweets`,
          value: `twitterrrr`,
          emoji: '938517355879870474'
        },
        {
          label: `YouTube Uploads`,
          value: `uploads`,
          emoji: '879396250213027880'
        },
```

everything starts working fine. Hm.